# In glsl 150 core, can a non-constant value be converted into a constant?

Tags: glsl, shader, amd-gpu

In this snippet of code, on amd graphics cards I get the error that a non constant can't be applied to const highp float. It is important that it is a constant so the exp2 operation isn't run multiple times in the program.

```
#define BLOOM

vec3 GetBloomTile(vec2 offset, vec2 
pixelSize, const float lod) {
    #ifndef BLOOM
        return vec3(0.0);
    #endif

    const highp float lodFactor = exp2(lod);
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken this is only a constant expression if the `lod` argument is supplied by an uniform, thus it only "becomes valid" after the driver did optimization on it and inlined and substituted its arguments...

Comment: `#define BLOOM

uniform float lod;
vec3 GetBloomTile(vec2 offset, vec2 pixelSize, float lod) {
    #ifndef BLOOM
        return vec3(0.0);
    #endif
    const highp float lodFactor = exp2(lod);`

Even with this new code, the same error occurs.

Comment: That's not what I meant... defining an argument as `const` means it cannot be changed within the scope of the function body, it's still not a constant expression required for defining a constant variable. Your shader only works(on nvidia cards) because the shader optimizer rewrites(and probably inlines) your actual function call so that the compiler only sees you passing a uniform to `exp2` which then becomes a [valid constant expression](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Core_Language_(GLSL)#Constant_expression).

Comment: Or to put it in different terms, your code is not valid as it is.

Comment: Also note the section about "Dynamically uniform expression" in that link

Comment: Ahh, I think I know what you mean, I'll try to find a solution to make it a constant variable.